# Find the generating function of the solutions $\geq 0$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I have to find the generating function of the number of non-negative integer solutions to the equation
$$
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 +x_5 = n$$
given the constraints that $x_2$ is even and $x_3$ is odd.

Context: I am an undergrad student just beginning to work with generating functions

Comment: I used [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to edit your question.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+...$ is the generating function of the number of solutions of $x=n$. When you multiply it by itself a few times, you get the generating function of the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$. This is because to get terms of degree $n$ you multiply from each factor terms, which sum of the exponents is $n$. Now, if some variable is supposed to be even, we can make the corresponding factor only even $\frac{1}{1-x^2}=1+x^2+x^4+...$. Similar for odd $\frac{x}{1-x^2}=x+x^3+x^5+...$